# Npgsql: Can it recognize ODBC espace sequences?

Tags: c#, postgresql, odbc, npgsql, postgresql-9.1

I have this SQL query (in T-SQL):

```
--DECLARE @strTerm varchar(300) 
--SET @strTerm = 'c' 


SELECT TOP 10 
   USR_ID 
  ,USR_UserName
FROM T_Benutzer 

WHERE (1=1) 
--AND {fn LCASE(USR_UserName)} LIKE {fn LCASE(@strTerm + '%')} 
AND {fn LCASE(BE_User)} LIKE {fn LCASE({fn CONCAT(@strTerm, '%')} )} 
--AND BE_Hide = 0  
AND BE_Hide = 'false' 

ORDER BY USR_UserName
```

Then, I have an automagic regex transform which I can switch on, to make the top syntax compatible with PostgreSQL, which generates the following output statement from the input statement:

```
SELECT 
   USR_ID 
  ,USR_UserName 
FROM T_Benutzer 
WHERE (1=1) 
AND {fn LCASE(BE_User)} LIKE {fn LCASE({fn CONCAT(@strTerm, '%')} )} 
AND BE_Hide = 'false' 
ORDER BY USR_UserName 
LIMIT 10
```

I thought this should suffice to get most things working on PostgreSQL, but now I realize that Npgsql doesn't recognize ODBC escape sequences ({fn whatever()}).

Is there any option in the Npgsql connectionstring settings that I can turn on, or in Postgres itself?
Or am I out of luck, and have to write an ODBC escape functions replace function?

Comment: Note that I don't want to use the ODBC driver itselfs, since the mono implementation of the wrapper around ODBC is of questionable quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PostgreSQL server itself does not have any escape syntax for functions like that. The  whole purpose of this escape syntax is to abstract several DB dialects. Moving exactly this into a specific server would be dubious at best.

The [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) manual does not mention any escape processing nor connection string parameters for that purpose.

So you are out of luck.

Comment: Wrong. It's true that Npgsql does not support it, so I WAS out of luck. But by now (after the week-end), I've written an ODBC escape sequence syntax parser and replacer. Works great, including nested statements resolution via recursion.